# Hide specific word from sentence using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I know jQuery but I am bit noob in RegEx.

```
<span class="subscription-price"> 
    <span class="amount">$15</span> / month with a 29-day free trial
</span>
```

I want to hide with a 29-day free trial (with a XX-day free trial) from this, Is it is possible using jQuery RegEx ? or any other method ?

Result I want is

```
 "$15 / month" Instead of "$15 / month with a 29-day free trial"
```

Thanks in advance,
Ajay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the words entirely:

```
$('.subscription-price').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('.amount')[0].nextSibling;
    text.nodeValue = text.nodeValue.replace('29-day free trial','');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kE2hf/).

To remove everything following the first `span`:

```
$('.subscription-price').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find('.amount')[0].nextSibling;
    text.parentNode.removeChild(text);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kE2hf/1/).

To hide it, you'll need to wrap in another element in order for CSS to target those words:

```
$('.subscription-price').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace('29-day free trial', function(a){
        return '<span class="hideMe">' + a + '</span>';
    });
});
```

Coupled with the CSS:

```
span.hideMe {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kE2hf/2/).

Or, again, to hide *everything* following the `span`:

```
$('.subscription-price').each(function(i,h){
    var text = $(this).find('span')[0].nextSibling;
    $(text).wrap('<span class="hideMe"></span>');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kE2hf/3/).

To, again, hide the part '29-days...', allowing for various numbers to be used instead of `29`:

```
$('.subscription-price').html(function(i,h){
    return h.replace(/(\d{1,2}-.+)/, function(a){
        console.log(a);
        return '<span class="hideMe">' + a + '</span>';
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kE2hf/5/).

Obviously, to hide *everything* following the `.amount` element the jQuery snippet previous to the last code-block would still work, since it's not hidden based on the number, but its location in the DOM.

Comment: What id 29 will be any value ? like 19,25,10

Comment: Will they always be numbers, will they always be two digits? Is it *just* the '29-day...' part, or *all* the text following the `span`?

Comment: always be no and it will be 1-31

Answer (score 1):

Use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var myStr = $('.subscription-price').text().replace(/ with a \d\d?-day free trial/g,'');
```

and then set it as text so it 'hides'

```
$('.subscription-price').text(myStr);
```

So now you replaced ' with a XX-day free trial' with ''(empty string).

Comment: $15 / month with a 29-day free trial  -> $15 / month

Comment: you can set the new string as text then to your span

Comment: updated my answer. Also made the second digit optional, you may have single digit days at some point

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
   var txt=$('.subscription-price').html().split('with ')[0];
   $('.subscription-price').html(txt);
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/p3vs6/

Answer (score 1):

If the text stays the same at all times, you could use this:

```
var price_html = $(".subscription-price").html();
$(".subscription-price").html(price_html.replace(" with a 29-day free trial", ""));
```

Here's take a look: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fVTa2/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: If the days(29) are dynamic then?

Answer (score 0):

Try This ...

```
$('.subscription-price').each(function(){
var text = $(this).find('.amount')[0].nextSibling;
text.nodeValue = text.nodeValue.replace('/\s*month.*','');
});
```